# What is the "Acutal vmId" in Azure?

Tags: azure

I came across this article from 2014 that mentioned that the UUID presented in the OS is different in to the "actual VM id" due to Big Endian Bit Ordering. But I've found that the UUID gotten by `sudo dmidecode | grep UUID` is the same as the one got from seen in azure portal (via the JSON view).
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/accessing-and-using-azure-vm-unique-id/

The the vmId and UUID do seem like they are the same thing going by [vmid docs](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.virtualmachine.vmid?view=azure-dotnet). Both of them saying that the id is a "a 128-bits identifier that is encoded and stored in all Azure IaaS VMs SMBIOS and can be read using platform BIOS commands"

Is "Big Endian Bit Ordering" not used as that blog indicates and the UUID reported by the OS is exactly the same as the VMid in azure portal. Is it just that I'm getting something completely wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Due to differences in endianness , Azure Linux VM's used to be reported their uuid values with the bits flipped, as recently as maybe six months ago.  However recently Azure Linux VMs seem to be reporting in the correct order, likely due to updates to the Azure LInux VM agent, which was responsible for the flipping of bits.  I am investigating and will post an answer when I have confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

> What is UUID and How to find it?

The 16 bytes that make up a universally unique identifier (UUID), which has a 128-bit value and is used to identify data in computer systems, are separated by spaces. Microsoft uses the term globally unique identifier (GUID) to refer to a specific UUID variant or as a synonym for UUID.

Every virtual machine has a UUID, which is also displayed on the OS as a guest UUID.

**PowerCLI:** Run the below simple command to find VM’s UUID:

```
Get-VM <vm_name> | %{(Get-View $_.Id).config.uuid}
```

> Find Windows Guest UUID

Use “Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line“:

```
wmic csproduct get name,identifyingnumber,UUID
```

VM Id and UUId are not the same.

Comment: So how do the VMid and UUid differ?
Also it seems that those commands don't apply to azure

Comment: GUID for azure refers to the resource type, it does not uniquely identify a specific resource